# Objective-C - Run code without freezing app

Tags: objective-c, download

Im working on a project which downloads some data from the internet but whenever I open the view containing the download code the app freezes/pauses until finished downloading.

Where (under which method) is the best place to have to code so the app does not temporally freeze/pause while downloading?

This is what I'm using now:

```
UERootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url to file"]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your (clearly incorrect) code for downloading.

Comment: I have update my question with my code @matt

Comment: How are you planning to initialize an _array_ from this downloaded data?

Comment: Anyway I've given you some minimal code. But there's a blank because I don't understand how you expect to get from an NSData (that is what is downloaded) to an NSArray.

Comment: The file is a .plist file.

Comment: Okay, I rewrote my code. You're going to want to assign to an instance variable (property) on the main thread.

Comment: I copied your modified code in and made _UERootArray_ a property but I NSLoged _UERootArray_ and it logs _nil_? @matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably downloading synchronously. Don't. Always download asynchronously; that means the downloading takes place in the background, off the main thread, and does not freeze your interface.

Here's a rewrite of your code (iOS 7 only) that does this work asynchronously:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url to file"];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask* task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *loc, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:loc];
    });
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any easy way to do this, or any good tutorials. Sorry I don't really know much, I'm kind of new to Objective C

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, you didn't show your code. Edit your question to show what you're doing, as requested.

Comment: The file is a .plist file @matt